# SendGrid - setHtml or setText mandatory even if i use setTemplateId?

Tags: sendgrid

I'm using SendGrid(https://sendgrid.com/) to send emails from my application. I have query regarding the usage of SendGrid SMTP API.

I'm having SendGrid template,myTemplateId,in which "newPwd" as substitution variable. In java, i defined like this:

```
SendGrid.Email email=new SendGrid.Email();
email.addTo(toEmailId);
email.setFrom(fromId);
email.setSubject(subject);
email.setTemplateId("myTemplateId");
email.addSubstitution("#newPwd#", new String[]{"myNewPwd"});
SendGrid.Response response=sendGrid.send(email);
```

When i run this, i'm getting below error response:

```
{"errors":["Missing email body"],"message":"error"}
```

If i set, `email.setHtml("withsomedummytext")` its working fine. But this is displaying the unwanted text in the email body. I don't know how can i avoid this.

But i don't understand why should i set body if i have template which defines body. Am i missing something here? Can anyone please clarify.

I posted the same question in sendgrid community 3days ago. But i dont see any response from community members.

https://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/sethtml-or-settext-mandatory-even-if-i-use-settemplateid

So trying here.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a space as the value for the body. This is an artifact of the templates being added to the existing endpoint. The next version of the mail.send API will fix this.

This is unrelated to your question, but sending passwords, even temporary ones, via email is not a good security practice. The user should have to enter some security question or other information to confirm their identity, then define the new password themselves via a form. You should then send a note via email that the password has changed.

Comment: Hi @bwest.. i tried with space before posting this.. sorry for not mentioning this in my question.. its replacing the subject as body param if i send space in setHtml or setText. :(

Comment: by the way, this is just for testing mailing functionality with templates.. we are not going to deploy this in production... anyways, thanks for the suggestion.. :)